# ¿Es posible prevenir la selección de índices específicos en un JList?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

En mi código hice un DefaultListSelectionModel para hacer mejor seleccionar y borrar la selección al hacer click en un elemento, ahora quiero ver si es posible que, en el mismo DefaultListSelectionModel, agregar que no permita la selección de ciertos índices. Antes hice un array con los índices que no quiero que se seleccionen. Aquí mi código:

```
TodasTAGSMuestra.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel() {
                    
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    
                    boolean gestureStarted = false;
                    
                    @Override
                    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
                        if(!gestureStarted) {
                            if(isSelectedIndex(index0)) {
                                super.removeSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                            }else {
                                super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                            }
                        }
                        gestureStarted = true;
                    }
                    
                    @Override
                    public void setValueIsAdjusting(boolean isAdjusting) {
                        if(isAdjusting == false);
                        gestureStarted = false;
                    }
                    
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Código probado y funcional, evita que los índices dentro de un array (En este caso llamado "TAGSNoSeleccionables") sean seleccionadas. Solo agregué una condición con un "OR" en la parte de setSelectionInterval en el if.

```
TodasTAGSMuestra.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel() {
                    
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    
                    boolean gestureStarted = false;
                    
                    @Override
                    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
                        if(!gestureStarted) {
                            if(isSelectedIndex(index0) || IntStream.of(TAGSNoSeleccionables).anyMatch(x -> x == index0)) {
                                super.removeSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                            }else {
                                super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                            }
                        }
                        gestureStarted = true;
                    }
                    
                    @Override
                    public void setValueIsAdjusting(boolean isAdjusting) {
                        if(isAdjusting == false);
                        gestureStarted = false;
                    }
                    
                });
```